# Return a specific value from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array ($myArray):

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d [4] => e [5] => f [6] => g [7] => h [8] => i )
```

Which I then split into chunks:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($myArray, 3);
```

Which leaves me with this multi-dimensional array output ($chunks):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => d [1] => e [2] => f )
    [2] => Array ( [0] => g [1] => h [2] => i )
)
```

I then need to populate another array ($myInsert) as such:

```
$myInsert = array(

    'sku1_sku'      => // "a" from chunk [0]
    'sku1_name'     => // "b" from chunk [0]
    'sku1_img'      => // "c" from chunk [0]

    'sku2_sku'      => // "d" from chunk [1]
    'sku2_name'     => // "e" from chunk [1]
    'sku2_img'      => // "f" from chunk [1]

    'sku3_sku'      => // "g" from chunk [2]
    'sku3_name'     => // "h" from chunk [2]
    'sku3_img'      => // "i" from chunk [2]

);
```

Big picture, I want to loop through each chunk of an array and write each value within that chunk, to another array.

My question: **How do I pull out specific values from a multi-dimensional array?**

**Solution:**

```
<?php

$myArray = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i");

$myInsert = array(
    'something1' => "CAT",
    'something2' => "HAT",
    'something3' => "BAT"
    );

$chunks = array_chunk($myArray, 3);

foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk)
{

    list($sku, $name, $img) = $chunk;
    $x = $i + 1;
    $myInsert["sku{$x}_sku"] = $sku;
    $myInsert["sku{$x}_name"] = $name;
    $myInsert["sku{$x}_img"] = $img;

}

print_r($myInsert);

?>
```

**Resulting output of $myInsert:**

```
array (
    'something1' => 'CAT',
    'something2' => 'HAT',
    'something3' => 'BAT',
    'sku1_sku'   => 'a',
    'sku1_name'  => 'b',
    'sku1_img'   => 'c',
    'sku2_sku'   => 'd',
    'sku2_name'  => 'e',
    'sku2_img'   => 'f',
    'sku3_sku'   => 'g',
    'sku3_name'  => 'h',
    'sku3_img'   => 'i',
)
```

Comment: The problem is that you have an array of arrays. Your first loop leaves you with several passes of arrays. The second loop, wil leave you with one single value. You seem to be under the impression you have multiple values accessible there, but you don't. See @mc10 's answer -> there's only one foreach there, which is logical. If you are going to need multiple loops, you need code that handles 1 element, not muliptle.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow you. The first loop iterates through each chunk of the array. The second loop, then iterates through each key:value pair within that chunk which does in fact leave me with multiple values.

Comment: Not within that second loop it doesn't, it's one value per 'round'. Anyway, I see you accepted the answer in which you don't need a second loop: that was my point :)

Comment: You are totally right. Your suggestion just went **swoosh** right over my head. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access each of the elements all at once:

```
$myInsert = array();
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk)
{
    list($chunk_sku, $chunk_name, $chunk_img) = $chunk;
    $myInsert["sku{$i}_sku"] = $chunk_sku;
    $myInsert["sku{$i}_name"] = $chunk_name;
    $myInsert["sku{$i}_img"] = $chunk_img;
}
```

Comment: Learned something new with list(), but alas, is not what I am looking for. I want $varCAT, $varBAT and $varHAT to return SPECIFIC values from the array, in my example "d", "e", and "f". These three values are part of the "second" chunk.

Comment: @Crayons Can you simply just access the second chunk? i.e. with `$chunk = $chunks[1];`.

Comment: I can, but that's not what I'm after. I think I'm just doing a bad job wording this question, i'm sorry. This chunked array is an array of products. The number of products (chunks) in the array varies. These products must be inserted into a single database row. I assemble what belongs in each column in a separate array ($myInsert). So I need to loop through every chunk in $myArray, and then assign every value to a specific value in the $myInsert array.

Comment: @Crayons Can you provide an example of what's in `$chunks` and what the expected output is? You seem to refer to `$myArray` and `$myInsert`, but that doesn't exist anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware you could just insert items into an array directly like that (   **$myArray[] = blah**   ). Original posted updated to show solution. Thank you mc10!